# How do I change ctrl and clicking to be interpreted as separate functions and not as right-clicking?

Tags: macos, keybindings, click, contextual-menu, karabiner

Karabiner has the option to disable ctrl-clicking entirely and register it as regular clicking, but that’s not what I want. In many videogames, Ctrl and Click are buttons you use simultaneously all the time, and I wanted to know if it’s possible to register those two without right-clicking.

What I want to happen when ctrl-clicking:
Ctrl + Click, no right click input

What actually happens:
Right click

What Karabiner does:
Click

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!